# volver a hacer push en otra rama

Tags: git

Estoy trabajando en una rama remota (new_theme) desde mi repositorio local.

Al hacer los cambios en el código hice push a new_theme. El problema es que me informaron que están trabajando en otra rama, branch update. ¿Cómo sería el procedimiento para volver a tener los commit preparados del código que yo modifique para pushearlo en esa nueva rama?

Comment: Cambiate a la rama update y has un pull.  Luego haces git merge new_theme y luego haces push.

Comment: Me tira este error error: Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente.

1.- Primero tienes que actualizar tu repositorio local, esto lo haces con

```
git fetch
```

2.- Debido a que ya hiciste un push y no hubo problemas asumo que no tienes ningun cambio sin commitear, siendo asi cambiate a otra_rama.

```
git checkout otra_rama
```

3.- Ahora puedes traerte todos los commits haciendo un rebase

```
git rebase origin/new_theme
```

4.- Usa git log para verificar.

```
git log
```

5.- Has push ha tus cambios.

```
git push origin otra_rama
```

Espero y te ayude

Comment: hola javier, gracias por contestar. El tema es que yo hice un push a new_theme con los cambios realizados desde esa rama en mi entorno local. Pero el problema es que ahora estan trabajando en la rama update y quieren que pushee esos mismos cambios en dicha rama. hice un git ceckout -b update y luego un git pull origin update. de ahi hice un git merge new_theme pero me tira el error que comente arriba

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta, si tienes algun error comentalo para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Cannot rebase: Your index contains uncommitted changes.
Please commit or stash them. me tira esa advertencia

Comment: Podrias hacer un git status y decirme que te dice.

Comment: cuando querio hacer el checkout otra_rama me tira esto: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:

Comment: ahi hice el checkout a otra_rama y cuando hago el rebase me dice Cannot rebase: Your index contains uncommitted changes.
Please commit or stash them.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que tienes cambios que no se han subido, has un git stash luego has el rebase y luego git stash pop